# Can I fit a valve with 15mm connections without replacing 22mm pipework?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have an existing shower valve with 22mm connections to the water supply. I bought a new valve for a plumber to fit, but now I see that it has 15mm inlet connections.

Both units are exposed, surface mounted, thermostatic valves.

Before I book a plumber should I return the unit and buy one with 22mm connections, or can my unit be fitted without chipping the tiles off the bathroom wall and getting at the pipes?

Comment: Most shower heads have a flow restrictors built in in the US the restriction is quite small less less than 1/2 or 1/3 the size of the 15 mm pipe I would not be concerned with the flow rate at 15mm. 
If you use an answer give it an up vote so others can find the accepted answer and give thanks to the one answering.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I will accept an answer once the matter is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you find a 22mm-15mm adapter?
I live on the other side of the pond and to change sizes there are adapters both male and female to make the change.

I just googled a “22mm to 15mm pipe adapter” and a brass piece for $6.69 came up on the first page.
[adapter](https://www.ebay.com/i/193561090553?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=193561090553&targetid=1068484833562&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=9033030&poi=&campaignid=11613469365&mkgroupid=114637654033&rlsatarget=pla-1068484833562&abcId=9300455&merchantid=6296724&gclid=CjwKCAiAl4WABhAJEiwATUnEF6vq1sRfCxul6HuxxThYhW-YC2btpVJpNGNFUlqoxFsZ51gqpdwsIBoCUukQAvD_BwE)

We use national pipe thread so I don’t know if that would work but try it.
It is a male thread so it should screw in and then female so your new piece would screw into that if the thread pitch is correct.

Comment: This is what I suspected. My plumber told me to send the shower back and get a 22 compatible one. He said getting it to fit was a big job. This sounded weak to me, so I came here for a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The risk is that the new valve might choke the flow of water to your shower heads. If you are just installing a single shower head, using traditional small piping, that's not an issue. If you have a deluxe bath with multiple fixtures, etc., then choking down from 22 to 15mm might reduce the flow enough to be a problem.

Comment: This is indeed just a single shower head. The property is a two flat building and my understanding is that it shares a mains supply which splits off from 22 to 2x15mm supplies anyway. I have no idea why the fittings are 22 other than the old shower valve is 22. Maybe the pipes aren't (?) Out of my depth here.